# A loop fills in only one vector of the ones I included in the for

Tags: r, loops, vector

I include some context. My problem is in the for. When I run it, only the vector intL is filled, but that doesn't happen with the intU. On the other hand, if I run a separate for, one for intL and one for intU, I get both vectors filled up. My question is though why when I do the for to fill up both vectors, only the intL vector is filled, but not the other one?

```
X<-replicate(1000,rnorm(n=10,mean=-1.2, sd=0.04))

Xbar<-c()

for(i in 1:1000){
  sumX<-(1/10)*sum(X[,i])
  Xbar[i]<-sumX
}

Xbar

intL<-c()
intU<-c()

for(i in 1:1000){
 intL[i]<-Xbar[i]-1.645*(.04/sqrt(10)) 
 intU[i]<Xbar[i]+1.645*(.04/sqrt(10))
}
```

Comment: Side comment: One one line you have `sumX <- ...`, on the next line you have `Xbar[i] <- sumX`, and you don't use `sumX` anywhere else. Might as well just do `Xbar[i] <- (1/10) * sum(X[, i])` and save a line... but of course you could skip the loop entirely and use `Xbar <- colSums(X) / 10`, or `Xbar <- colMeans(X)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `<`

```
intU[i]<Xbar[i]+1.645*(.04/sqrt(10))
```

should be `<-`

```
intU[i]<- Xbar[i]+1.645*(.04/sqrt(10))
```

Running the code again with corrected version

```
intL<-c()
intU<-c()

for(i in 1:1000){
   intL[i] <- Xbar[i]-1.645*(.04/sqrt(10)) 
   intU[i] <- Xbar[i]+1.645*(.04/sqrt(10))

 }

length(intU)
#[1] 1000
length(intL)
#[1] 1000
```

---

`<` is comparison operator which simply checks whether 'intU[i]' (it is initialized as `NULL`) is less than the calculated value, while `<-` is assignment operator